cutoff function for fundamental solution
Consider the fundamental solution $h(x)=c_{n}|x|^{-(n-2)}$ defined for $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $x\neq 0$ with $c_{n}$ a normalizing constant. Is there some way to define a new function $H$ so that it is zero outside a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$, i.e., $H(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\overline{\Omega}$ and $H(x)=h(x)$ for $x\in \overline{\Omega}$.
My approach: If we consider $f$ a cutoff function such that $0\leq f\leq 1$, $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $f=0$ in $\overline{\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\Omega}$, $f=1$ in $\Omega$, then $H(x):=fh(x)$ satisfies $H\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $H=0$ in $\overline{\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\Omega}$ and $H=h$ in $\Omega$.
I'm not sure if this is ok, as I have a singularity and there may be issues with the boundary of $\Omega$.
Any idea it will be great, thanks!

What does cutting the function off have to do with $h$ being a fundamental solution (of the Laplace equation?) Are you just asking whether you can smoothly restrict a function to a bounded domain?

@whpowell96 That is, I am asking if it is possible to restrict a function $H$ to a limited domain, such that $H=h$ in $\Omega$ and $H=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\overline{\Omega}$, thanks!
